# I need an help to calculate this differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have to calculate this equation

$$\frac{d^{2}V}{dx^{2}}=\frac{J}{\varepsilon (2eV/m)^{\frac{1}{2}}}$$

can someone link me the theory or a book where i can learn how to do it ?
Thanks

Comment: Can you define which is a variable, function, constant? What have you tried?

Comment: I dont know how a differential equation so defined is called.(i know there are many types of differential equations).  Because I would study the theory

Comment: the solution looks terrible!

Comment: Anyway it's a second order differential equation. But, V in the second term is in the denominator. What type of equation is ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{d^{2}V}{dx^{2}}=\frac{C}{\sqrt{V}}\qquad \text{with}\quad C=\frac{J}{\varepsilon (2e/m)^{\frac{1}{2}}}$$ 
$$2\frac{d^{2}V}{dx^{2}}\frac{dV}{dx}=\frac{2C}{\sqrt{V}}\frac{dV}{dx}$$
$$\left(\frac{dV}{dx}\right)^2= 4C\sqrt{V}+c_1$$
$$\frac{dV}{dx}=\pm\sqrt{4C\sqrt{V}+c_1}$$
$$dx=\pm\frac{dV}{\sqrt{4C\sqrt{V}+c_1}}$$
$$x=\pm\int\frac{dV}{\sqrt{4C\sqrt{V}+c_1}}$$
$$x=\pm\frac{1}{6C^2}\left(2C\sqrt{V}-c_1 \right)\sqrt{4C\sqrt{V}+c_1} \:+c_2$$
You can solve this equation for $V$ : The change of variable $\sqrt{V}=X$ leads to a quadratic equation to be solved for $X$. Take care to eliminate the surabondant solutions introduced by the squaring $V=X^2$.

Comment: Thanks. Could you suggest me a site or a book where i can learn this procedure ?

Comment: This is an ODE of the so called "autonomous" kind. The method of solving can be found in any book dealing with ODEs. See : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonomous_system_(mathematics) In the present case, it is even simpler to multiply both terms by $dV/dx$ in order to make appear the derivative of $V^2$.